# Spring Security - Dynamic/Runtime change the password encoder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, spring-security, spring-boot

I have created the spring security application which running smoothly,Currently i am using SHA-1 encoding technology but i want to support to MD5 Encryption technology

```
<!-- This will override the settings of authentication manager bean. -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="umsUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="sha"/> 
    </authentication-provider>
    <authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Above is configuration setting for SHA-1 encryption.Now i want to support to MD5 algorithm also,

I have store the current algorithm in database want to support that only so it will be MD5 or SHA-1 whenever we can change the encryption algorithm it will runtime reflect to that/ support to that algorithm.

To support this type flow what changes need to do?

Comment: Please do not use MD5 as it is completely broken way of storing passwords.

Comment: Thanks for reply will make sure the prevent use of MD5

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer we can do this by implement following solution.

```
public class MyPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder{
     @Override
     public String encodePassword(String rawPass, Object salt)
        throws DataAccessException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isPasswordValid(String encPass, String rawPass, Object salt)
        throws DataAccessException {
   }
}
```

And add this bean in the application context file.